# Invariance of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given the Lebesgue integral with the Lebesgue measure and the Borel-Sigma Algebra, I am supposed to figure out under which transformations $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x) dx$ the integral is invariant(notice that $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$

Reflection,
Rotation,
Translation,
Shearing.

The first two are clear, since they are isometries. Translation also preserves the volume(basically substitution will do it). Shearings should also be integral preserving, but I do not know how to properly point out why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix of a shear is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$ which has determinant one, so the standard change of variables formula should do the trick.